# Response.Write started adding Hex characters in the begining and end of all export files ( xml, zip, xls )

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are presenting the files created using different ways to user in web application using below mentioned code but recently (since last week) all files started to have HEX character at the beginning and 0 in the end line; [see image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T2Ei.jpg) This makes the files invalid. If we save the file and remove first and last line the files become good. Also the issue is not with the file creation; its only when its presented to the user. If we go to the temporary app folder where we create files on web server the files are good. Only the response is creating some issue.

Any idea what could have triggered this thing. How can we fix this.

We tried uninstalling few recent windows updates but nothing changed.

Win Server: 2008 R2 Service Pack1

.Net Framework: 3.5

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + <string>);
Response.Flush();
Response.BinaryWrite(<byte[]>);
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Thanks